# how do I make this pop up extension more generic to be applied to any view?

Tags: ios, swift

I have edited a pop up extension I found on github to the following

PopUpExtension.swift :

```
import UIKit
extension (Home)
{
//Call this method in view did load
func PopUpInit()
{
    createOverlay()
    createAlert()
}


func createOverlay()
{
    let p = CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.origin.x, self.view!.frame.origin.y, self.view!.bounds.size.width, self.view!.bounds.size.height)
    overlayView = UIView(frame: p)
    overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    overlayView.alpha = 0.0
    self.view!.addSubview(overlayView)
}

func createAlert()
{
    let alertWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    let alertHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    let alertViewFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0, alertWidth, alertHeight)

    alertView = UIView(frame: alertViewFrame)
    alertView.center = self.view.center
    alertView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    alertView.alpha = 0.0

    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    button.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "dismissAlert", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.center.x = alertView.center.x

    let button1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect)
    button1.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 80.0, 80.0)
    button1.addTarget(self, action: "Button1", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button1.center.x = alertView.center.x

    let button2 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect)
    button2.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 80.0, 80.0)
    button2.addTarget(self, action: "Button2", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button2.center.x = alertView.center.x

    let button3 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect)
    button3.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button3.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button3.frame = CGRectMake(100, 300, 80.0, 80.0)
    button3.addTarget(self, action: "Button3", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button3.center.x = alertView.center.x

    alertView.addSubview(button)
    alertView.addSubview(button1)
    alertView.addSubview(button2)
    alertView.addSubview(button3)
    self.view!.addSubview(alertView)

}

func showAlert()
{
    if (alertView == nil)
    {
        createAlert()
    }
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3)
        {
            self.overlayView.alpha = 0.5
            self.alertView.alpha = 1.0
    }
}

func dismissAlert()
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.15, animations:
        {
            self.overlayView.alpha = 0.0
            self.alertView.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion:
        {
            (value: Bool) in
            self.alertView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.alertView = nil
    })
}

func Button1()
{
    print("button1")
}

func Button2()
{
    print("button2")
}

func Button3()
{
    print("button3")
}

}
```

now in Home.swift view controller, I just do the following

```
import UIKit

class Home: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        self.PopUpInit()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    var overlayView: UIView!
    var alertView: UIView!
    var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!

}
```

the question is :

how do I convert this extension into a class that I can use where ever I need, not only from Home.swift, also I want to avoid the need to define these into all classes that use this pop up

```
var overlayView: UIView!
var alertView: UIView!
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
```

can you guide me to the **best** way to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to making this more `generic` is to make it more `protocol-oriented`. With `protocols` you can leverage `default implementations` where you define what the `conforming type` will need to be like and use the `extension` to implement methods.

---

**Stuff:**

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

**PopUpAble:**

This will be your main `protocol`. Anything that has a `view` variable can be made `PopUpAble`.

```
@objc protocol PopUpAble : class {

    var view : UIView! { get set }

    func button1()
    func button2()
    func button3()

    func alertWillDismiss() -> Bool
    func alertDidDismiss()

    func dismissAlert()

}
```

---

**Types for identification:**

These are `protocols` and `conforming classes` to be able to distinguish the `alertView` and `overlayView` without needing to assign them to `attributes`. Less boilerplate code -> Better

```
protocol AlertType : class {}

protocol OverlayType : class {}

class AlertView : UIView, AlertType {}

class OverlayView : UIView, OverlayType {}
```

---

**The Implementation:**

This is the same collection of `functions` as you had, only modified to use what is available in the `PopUpAble` `protocol`.

- `create...` functions now search for existing matching types or create
- no more setup function, was not needed
- optional animation
- set order of views before/after show/hide

This all makes it more versatile and less needs to implemented in the VC.

```
extension PopUpAble {

    func createOverlay() -> UIView {

        if let overlay = (view.subviews.filter { $0 is OverlayType }).first {
            return overlay
        }

        let p = CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.origin.x, self.view!.frame.origin.y, self.view!.bounds.size.width, self.view!.bounds.size.height)
        let overlayView = OverlayView(frame: p)
        overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        overlayView.alpha = 0.0
        view!.insertSubview(overlayView, atIndex: 0)

        return overlayView
    }

    func createAlert() -> UIView {

        if let alert = (view.subviews.filter { $0 is AlertType }).first {
            return alert
        }

        let alertWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
        let alertHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
        let alertViewFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0, alertWidth, alertHeight)

        let alertView = AlertView(frame: alertViewFrame)
        alertView.center = self.view.center
        alertView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        alertView.alpha = 0.0

        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        button.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Self.dismissAlert), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button.center.x = alertView.center.x

        let button1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect)
        button1.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 80.0, 80.0)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Self.button1), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button1.center.x = alertView.center.x

        let button2 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect)
        button2.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button2.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 80.0, 80.0)
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Self.button2), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button2.center.x = alertView.center.x

        let button3 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect)
        button3.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button3.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button3.frame = CGRectMake(100, 300, 80.0, 80.0)
        button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Self.button3), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button3.center.x = alertView.center.x

        alertView.addSubview(button)
        alertView.addSubview(button1)
        alertView.addSubview(button2)
        alertView.addSubview(button3)
        view!.insertSubview(alertView, atIndex: 1)

        return alertView

    }

    func showAlert(animated animated:Bool = true) {

        func show(alert:UIView,overlay:UIView) {
            if animated {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
                    overlay.alpha = 0.5
                    alert.alpha = 1.0
                }
            } else {
                overlay.alpha = 0.5
                alert.alpha = 1.0
            }
        }

        let overlay = createOverlay()
        let alert = createAlert()

        view.bringSubviewToFront(overlay)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(alert)

        show(alert, overlay: overlay)

    }

    func hideAlert(animated animated:Bool = true) {

        guard alertWillDismiss() else {
            return
        }

        func hide(alert:UIView,overlay:UIView) {
            if animated {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.15, animations: {
                    overlay.alpha = 0.0
                    alert.alpha = 0.0
                    }) {
                    if $0 {
                        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(alert)
                        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(overlay)
                        self.alertDidDismiss()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                overlay.alpha = 0.0
                alert.alpha = 0.0
                view.sendSubviewToBack(alert)
                view.sendSubviewToBack(overlay)
                alertDidDismiss()
            }
        }

        let overlay = createOverlay()
        let alert = createAlert()

        hide(alert, overlay: overlay)
    }
}
```

---

**The Works:**

`alertWillDismiss` and `alertDidDismiss` are not needed, but they follow nicely with the standard UIKit flow and give you more control.

```
class VC : UIViewController, PopUpAble {

    func button1() {
        print("button1")
    }

    func button2() {
        print("button2")
    }

    func button3() {
        print("button3")
    }

    func alertWillDismiss() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func alertDidDismiss() {
        print("dismissed")
    }

    func dismissAlert() { // this bridges between objc en swift
        self.hideAlert() 
    }

}


let vc = VC()
vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

vc.showAlert(animated: true)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = vc.view
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go is to get the current visible viewcontroller and present the alert on it. Instead of defining actions in a `UIViewController` subclass they are implemented in a `PopUp` object. When needed a `PopUp` is created from wherever and it will be displayed on the current VC.

---

**Stuff:**

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

---

**Current ViewController:**

Can't take the credit for this code, is from somewhere on SO. (if someone has a link?)

```
public extension UIWindow {

    var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
        return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(self.rootViewController)
    }

    private static func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nc = vc as? UINavigationController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(nc.visibleViewController)
        } else if let tc = vc as? UITabBarController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(tc.selectedViewController)
        } else {
            if let pvc = vc?.presentedViewController {
                return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(pvc)
            } else {
                return vc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Same as the other answer:**

```
protocol AlertType : class {}

protocol OverlayType : class {}

class AlertView : UIView, AlertType {}

class OverlayView : UIView, OverlayType {}
```

---

**The PopUp Object:**

Subclassing can be used to override the actions.

```
class PopUp : NSObject {

    func button1Tapped() {
        print("button1")
    }

    func button2Tapped() {
        print("button2")
    }

    func button3Tapped() {
        print("button3")
    }

   func alertWillDismiss() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func alertDidDismiss() {
        print("dismissed")
    }
```

---

This is now implemented in the `PopUp`
The `view` of the current VC is grabbed and used to display the alert.

```
    func createOverlay() -> UIView? {

        guard let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first, view = window.visibleViewController?.view else {
            return nil
        }

        if let overlay = (view.subviews.filter { $0 is OverlayType }).first {
            return overlay
        }

        let p = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height)
        let overlayView = OverlayView(frame: p)
        overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        overlayView.alpha = 0.0
        view.insertSubview(overlayView, atIndex: 0)

        return overlayView
    }

    func createAlert() -> UIView? {

        guard let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first, view = window.visibleViewController?.view else {
            return nil
        }

        if let alert = (view.subviews.filter { $0 is AlertType }).first {
            return alert
        }

        let alertWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
        let alertHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
        let alertViewFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0, alertWidth, alertHeight)

        let alertView = AlertView(frame: alertViewFrame)
        alertView.center = view.center
        alertView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        alertView.alpha = 0.0

        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        button.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissAlert), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button.center.x = alertView.center.x

        let button1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect)
        button1.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 80.0, 80.0)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button1Tapped), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button1.center.x = alertView.center.x

        let button2 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect)
        button2.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button2.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 80.0, 80.0)
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button2Tapped), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button2.center.x = alertView.center.x

        let button3 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect)
        button3.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button3.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button3.frame = CGRectMake(100, 300, 80.0, 80.0)
        button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button3Tapped), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button3.center.x = alertView.center.x

        alertView.addSubview(button)
        alertView.addSubview(button1)
        alertView.addSubview(button2)
        alertView.addSubview(button3)
        view.insertSubview(alertView, atIndex: 1)

        return alertView

    }

    func showAlert(animated animated:Bool = true) {

        guard let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first, view = window.visibleViewController?.view else {
            return
        }

        guard let overlay = createOverlay(), alert = createAlert() else {
            return
        }

        func show(alert:UIView,overlay:UIView) {
            if animated {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
                    overlay.alpha = 0.5
                    alert.alpha = 1.0
                }
            } else {
                overlay.alpha = 0.5
                alert.alpha = 1.0
            }
        }


        view.bringSubviewToFront(overlay)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(alert)

        show(alert, overlay: overlay)

    }

    func dismissAlert(animated animated:Bool = true) {

        guard let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first, view = window.visibleViewController?.view else {
            return
        }

        guard let overlay = createOverlay(), alert = createAlert() else {
            return
        }

        func hide(alert:UIView,overlay:UIView) {
            if animated {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.15, animations: {
                    overlay.alpha = 0.0
                    alert.alpha = 0.0
                    }) {
                    if $0 {
                        view.sendSubviewToBack(alert)
                        view.sendSubviewToBack(overlay)
                        self.alertDidDismiss()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                overlay.alpha = 0.0
                alert.alpha = 0.0
                view.sendSubviewToBack(alert)
                view.sendSubviewToBack(overlay)
                alertDidDismiss()
            }
        }

        hide(alert, overlay: overlay)
    }
}
```

---

**The Works:**

```
let vc = UIViewController()

let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
window.rootViewController = vc

vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = vc.view

let pop = PopUp()
pop.showAlert(animated: true)
```

---

**Note:**

I would remove the alert and overlay from the `view` after hiding. No need to keep them around.